# Can an array output different values each time it's called with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

If my array was something like

```
   greetings = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Hi", "Bye"]
```

Would it be possible for every time the array is called to have it output a different value?

Comment: how about `greetings.shuffle.pop`?
or is that not what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `greetings.shuffle.pop` is more readable :-)

```
user     system      total        real
sahil  0.000000   0.010000   0.010000 (  0.115553)
chrispanda  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000154)
tokland  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000008)
```

@tokland's is even neater and more efficient though

Comment: ... and by far less efficient (if that matters).

Comment: actually, it appears not - but tokland wins by a mile ... added the benchmarks into my answer

Comment: @chrispanda: don't get misleaded by micro-benchmarkings, undur_gondor is right from the theoretical sense: Array#shuffle makes it O(n), while this is a O(1) problem. If you try on arrays with millions of elements you should see the difference. Granted, here with so few elements it makes absolutely no difference (it's faster, apparently), but it's important to pick the right algorithms for every task.

Comment: you are correct (again) theoretically - but I think that for small arrays (the benchmark is on 1000 members) it is the call to rand that makes sahil's version slower

Comment: @tokland: Thanks. Besides that, the times in chrispanda's benchmark are way too small to show anything. I'm measuring (sahil -- 0.20, chrispanda -- 0.81, tokland -- 0.16) on my system (1000000 runs) even for the 4 element array. For larger arrays, chrispanda's version gets even worse (O(n)).

Comment: I'm actually only using 6 or so elements in my array, and I found that this method was the easiest to implement. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Ruby 1.8: `greetings.choice` ([Array#choice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-choice))

Ruby 1.9: `greetings.sample` ([Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-sample))

Answer (score 4):

```
greetings[rand(greetings.size)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
greetings = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Hi", "Bye"]
greeter = greetings.cycle


puts greeter.next
# do something else
5.times{ puts greeter.next}
```